# What is the expected behavior of running multiple `kubectl rollout restart` commands simultaneously?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Context: We have multiple processes that are watching the same feature flag to determine whether a restart is required, and trying to determine if we need to ensure that exactly one process calls `kubectl rollout restart`.

Suppose `n` processes simultaneously call `kubectl rollout restart` on the same deployment, for `n > 3`.
Which of the following behaviors is expected to happen?

1. The deployment goes down entirely as the overlapping restarts cause different pods to be deleted.
2. All the restarts eventually run, but they run serially.
3. Some number of restarts m, where m < n will run serially.
4. Something else.

I have searched around but haven't found documentation about this behavior, so a pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't find the official documentation explaining how Kubernetes will behave as presented in your question.

However, I wrote a script that will spawn the 5 rollout restart command in parallel and used the deployment.yaml below for testing, with rollingUpdate as strategy and maxSurge = maxUnavailable = 1.

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webapp1
spec:
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  replicas: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webapp1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webapp1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webapp1
        image: katacoda/docker-http-server:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

**script.sh**

```
for var in 1..5; do
        kubectl rollout restart deployment webapp1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
done
```

Then executed the script and watched the behavior

```
    . script.sh; watch -n .5 kubectl get po
```

The watch command revealed that the Kubernetes maintained the desired state as commanded by the deployment.yaml. AT no time, fewer than 9 pods were in the Running state. Screenshots were taken few seconds apart

[image]

[image]

So, from this experiment, I deduce that no matter how many parallel rollout-restarts occur, Kubernetes controller manager is smart enough to still maintain the desired state.

Hence, the expected behavior will be as described in your manifest.